# Is array different w/ and w/o GCC aligned attribute in rpi3?

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi

Currently I'm tracing the example of rpi3 mailbox and I found something weird.
According to [wiki](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/wiki/Mailbox-property-interface):

> The buffer itself is 16-byte aligned as only the upper 28 bits of the address can be passed via the mailbox.

and I found the [code](https://github.com/bztsrc/raspi3-tutorial/blob/master/04_mailboxes/mbox.c) might be relative with the description:

```cpp
volatile unsigned int  __attribute__((aligned(16))) mbox[36];
```

I think the author try to aligned it with 16 bytes but I dump the member's address in C code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
volatile unsigned int  __attribute__((aligned(16))) mbox[36];

int main()
{
    printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n", &mbox[0], &mbox[1], &mbox[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0x601040
0x601044
0x601048
```

I found it's 4 bytes aligned. My question is what is the purpose of this attribute in here or did it matter?

Comment: The alignment applies to the whole variable, i.e. the array, not its separate members. The array (`&mbox[0]`) is properly aligned to 16 bytes.

Comment: Can I claim only first member aligned with 16 bytes?

Comment: That's true. Array members are stored consecutive without any gaps and the address of the array is the address of the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is array different w/ and w/o GCC aligned attribute in rpi3?

Well, no, the array *itself* is not different, only the placement of the whole array is affected.

If you want like array elements to be aligned, do an array of aligned structures.

> I found it's 4 bytes aligned

Sure, elements of the array are 4 bytes aligned - looks like `int` has 4 bytes on your platform.

> My question is what is the purpose of this attribute in here

To make the array `mbox` aligned to 16, not its elements.

> did it matter?

Yes.